# How to update the date for a specific ID in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm setting up a database for a scuba diving company and have a SQL table with values for Student ID (`SID`), Instructor ID (`IID`), Item Borrowed (`ITEMID`), Equipment Borrow Date (`BorrowDate`), and Equipment Return Date (`ReturnDate`). How do I change the `Equipment Return Date` for one of the students? I'd like to add an extra 2 days to the `ReturnDate`. I created the Borrows table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE BORROWS(
  SID CHAR(15),
  ITEMID CHAR(15),
  IID CHAR(15),
  BORROW_DATE DATE,
  RETURN_DATE DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY(SID, ITEMID),
  FOREIGN KEY(SID) REFERENCES STUDENT(SID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(ITEMID) REFERENCES EQUIPMENT(ITEMID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(IID) REFERENCES INSTRUCTOR(SSN) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I tried doing this in my SQL file:

```
SELECT SID, ADD_DATE(RETURN_DATE, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
FROM BORROWS
WHERE SID = '005' AND IID = '108';
```

I'm getting this error back:

```
SELECT SID, ADD_DATE(RETURN_DATE, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Can't figure out where the error is in my code...

Comment: Did you mean `DATE_ADD()`? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Have you tried RETURN_DATE+2 in your query.SELECT SID,to_date(RETURN_DATE+2,'dd-mon-yyyy') FROM BORROWS WHERE SID = '005' AND IID = '108';

Comment: Whoops, yes, I mean DATE_ADD(). I had this in my program and was giving hte same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Adding two days to a date is as simple as + 2.

```
select return_date + 2 
from borrows 
where sid='005' 
and iid='108'
```

The syntax you are looking for might be:

```
select (return_date + INTERVAL '2' DAY)
    from borrows 
    where sid='005' 
    and iid='108'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out and let you know. Is the DATE_ADD() information on www.w3schools.com wrong (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)? They didn't mention anything about using a '+' operator or quotes around the 2 in their website.

Comment: Your question says SQL, ORACLE. Not SQL, MYSQL. So my answer is for Oracle database not MySQL.

Comment: Ah...I didn't notice the page was for MySQL. Yes, I'm looking for an Oracle SQL solution.

Comment: This worked, but created a new table with the updated dates. How do I get those dates to show up with SELECT * FROM BORROWS at the end of the file? I tried doing this but it's not working: INSERT INTO BORROWS (RETURN_DATE) VALUES (RETURN_DATE + 2) WHERE SID = '005' AND IID = '108';  The error message is "WHERE SID = '005' AND IID = '108'
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" Sorry I am very new to SQL.

Comment: @JIL: you want an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_dml.htm#TDDDG99941